# join mysql on self with group

Tags: mysql, pivot

table

```
 id | name | year
```

Data:

```
 1  | ham   | 2006
 2  | ham   | 2007
 3  | ham   | 2008
 4  | amm   | 2007
 5  | amm   | 2008
 6  | inn   | 2009
```

Now i'm trying to construct a sql that gives me the following output (or similar)

```
 name  | y1   | y2   | y3   | y4    
 ham   | 2006 | 2007 | 2008 | null
 amm   | null | 2007 | 2008 | null
 inn   | null | null | null | 2009
```

When doing multiple (self) left joins I kind of gets this, but only if 2006 is set for that name. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I do know the number of columns (= possible year-values are 2009,2010,2011,2012)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want what is called a "pivot", and call you need is a conditional `sum`:

```
select
   name,
   sum(year = 2006) as y1,
   sum(year = 2007) as y2,
   sum(year = 2008) as y3,
   sum(year = 2009) as y4
from mytable
group by name;
```

No joins, no muss, no fuss. And it will perform really well.

This works because in mysql, `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`, so summing a condition counts how many times it was true!

Note that this will give you zeroes instead of `null`s for "no data" years, which is probably better. If you really want nulls, use `if(sum(year = 2006) = 0, null, sum(year = 2006)) as y1` etc, but hopefully you don't need it.

Comment: +1 Actually I think the OP needs `if(sum(year = 2006) = 0, null, 2006) as y1` though.

Comment: I was just about to click 'Add Comment' with that `IF` suggestion :) Definitely think this is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way given your example ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6a91/2)):

```
SELECT t1.name, MAX(y1.year) AS y1, MAX(y2.year) AS y2, MAX(y3.year) AS y3, MAX(y4.year) AS y4
FROM theTable t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN theTable y1 ON t1.name = y1.name AND y1.year = 2006
LEFT OUTER JOIN theTable y2 ON t1.name = y2.name AND y2.year = 2007
LEFT OUTER JOIN theTable y3 ON t1.name = y3.name AND y3.year = 2008
LEFT OUTER JOIN theTable y4 ON t1.name = y4.name AND y4.year = 2009
GROUP BY t1.name
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work, but takes for ever to run :) so, the trick was to use the outer join... Again - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the structure of the result, you can use `group_concat`:

```
select name , group_concat(ifnull(year ,'null') separator ', ') 
              as years from table
```

which will display the result as:

```
name  | years
ham   | 2006 , 2007 , 2008 , null
amm   | null , 2007 , 2008 , null
inn   | null , null , null , 2009
```